# How to prevent PHP variables and expressions from expanding in string

Tags: php

The following text link works fine when I place it directly in my html:

```
<a href="http://example.com/index.php?g=<?php echo $grade; ?>&amp;s=<?php if($slcustom29 == 0) echo 1; else echo 0; ?>">Click here to <?php echo $showOrHideText; ?>  the suggested sequence of lessons.</a>
```

But I want to replace it with:

```
<?php echo $gradeNote; ?>
```

Elsewhere $gradeNote is assigned a string based on the grade of the student user. My question after many hours of searching and failing is how can I pass this snippet as a literal string, without PHP attempting to parse it and giving me a junk url? What am I doing wrong here:

```
$gradeNote = "<a href=\"http://example.com/index.php?g=<?php echo $grade; ?>&amp;s=<?php if($slcustom29 == 0) echo 1; else echo 0; ?>\">Click here to <?php echo $showOrHideText; ?>  the suggested sequence of lessons.</a>";
```

Comment: " giving me a junk url" what exactly do you get?

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: `=<?php echo $grade; ?>` is wrongly used in the statement `$gradeNote = ...`

Comment: Example of junk url I've been getting:    http://example.com/index.php?g=%3C?php%20echo%20-1;%20?%3E&s=%3C?php%20if(1%20==%200)%20echo%201;%20else%20echo%200;%20?%3E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running `<?php` and `?>` tags **inside** of a PHP variable. As you're already dealing with PHP, these are unnecessary.

Although the quotation marks `""` allow you to echo out evaluated variables, because you're also running a **condition** in this 'string', you'll want to extrapolate that out and simply store the result as a variable. I've called mine `$show`.

As such, you're simply looking for:

```
if($slcustom29 == 0) {
    $show = 1;
}
else {
    $show = 0;
}

$gradeNote = "<a href=\"http://example.com/index.php?g=$grade;&amp;s=$show\">Click here to $showOrHideText the suggested sequence of lessons.</a>";
```

Remember to either escape the double-quotes in the `<a href="">`, or swap them for single-quotes.

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/Rsg7Y)**.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
$s = ($slcustom29 == 0) ? 1 : 0;

$gradeNote = "<a href=\"http://example.com/index.php?g={$grade}&amp;s={$s}\">Click here to {$showOrHideText}  the suggested sequence of lessons.</a>";
```

Any string with double quotes "" can have a variable embedded, the {} are not necessary, but i always use them for cases like this where you are trying to embed a variable with no spaces around it, "$xabc" which will return a different result "{$x}ab"

Answer (score 1):

the probelm is that you are trying to put php logic into the string.  Notice you have an IF command within the string literal. start with a small or empty string, and concat onto it piece by piece, as opposed to doing it in one line.

then you can echo out the single variable link